# Add facebook feedback button to my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, message, inbox

I'm developing my own website and I would like to integrate it with my facebook page.
I would like to have small button or widget in my site that in case user wants to send feedback on my site he's clicking it and write down his message. This message is automatically sent to my facebook private messages (inbox) and I can reply to it.

Let me know if there is option like this? Do I need to develop new FB app for this?

Thank you,
Moshe

Comment: Facebook API can help  solve your issue!

Comment: Thank you. Can you give some more detailed explanation.